# Weighted Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I know that the Sobolev space $H^s$ with the inner product given by $$  \langle u,v \rangle_{H^s} := \sum_{| \alpha| \leqslant s} \int_{\Bbb R^n} \nabla^\alpha u \cdot \nabla^\alpha v $$ is Hilbert space. ($u = (u_1, \cdots , u_N), v = (v_1, \cdots ,v_N)$)

Then if we set the bracket as 
$$
 \langle u,v \rangle_{A,H^{s}} :=  \sum_{| \alpha| \leqslant s} \int_{\Bbb R^n} (A \nabla^\alpha u) \cdot \nabla^\alpha v 
$$

with $N \times N$ positive definite matrix $A$, then is $(H^s, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_{A, H^{s}} )   $ also Hilbert space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is again a Hilbert space, since the norms induced by the standard inner product and the one induced by $A$ are equivalent.